# Visual Studio Code on Mac warning: 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, visual-studio-code

I 've tried compiling/running the code on my mac, but it gave me a warning on Visual Studios.

> 'override' keyword is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

I've already tried doing the following:

File>>Preference>>Settings>>Extensions

find C_Cpp>Default:Cpp Standard drop down menu

set that to c++11

but it still doesn't work for. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I don't use VSCode for C++ but it's probably got more to do with configuring whatever it is you use to compile the code.  What is that?

Comment: How do I know what compiler I use for the code? I'm a total beginner. All I did was download the C++ extension and code runner extension. Then I click the ▶ button.

Comment: There will be some build output in one of the window showing the compiler invocation.  It's more than likely clang from Xcode disguised as `gcc`.  Try `gcc --version` to see.

Comment: This is what I got: configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix